# SSIS import from excel files with multiple sheets and different amount of columns

Tags: ssis

I have SSIS with 2 loops that loop over excel files and over the sheets. I have a data flow task in the for each sheet loop with variable name for sheetname and the source is excel and odbc destination.
The table in the db has all the columns I need such as userid, username, productname, supportname.
However, some sheets can have columns username, productname and others have userid, username, productname, supportname.

How can I load the excel files? Can I add columns to a derived column task that checks if a column exists and if not add it with a default value and then map it to the destination?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is a not an any format goes at run-time data loading engine. There was a conscious design decision to make the fastest possible ETL tool and one of those requirements was that they needed to define a contract between the data source's shape and the destination. That's why you'll inevitably run into VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA error because something has altered the shape and the package needs to be edited in designer mode to update the columns and sizes.

If you want to write the C# to make a generic Excel ingest engine, more power to you.

An alternative approach would be to have multiple data flows defined within your file and worksheet looping construct. The trick would be to conditionally enable them based on the available column set.

Columns "username and productname" detected, enable DFT UserName and ProductName. And that DFT will have default values, or a lookup, for UserId, SupportName, etc

All columns present, enable DFT All.

Finally, Azure Data Factory can "slurp and burp" whatever source to whatever destination. Perhaps that might be a better fit for your problem.